# Lightinject and xUnit InjectData

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, xunit, light-inject

I'm trying to setup [xUnit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/wiki) with the [LightInject](https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject) framework but cannot get the xUnit InlineDataAttribute to work. The following test code doesn't work:

```
public static void Configure(IServiceContainer container)
{
    container.Register<FooController>();                        
}

[Theory, InjectData, InlineData("data")]
public void Test_GetViolations_Should_Return_A_Non_Empty_List(FooController service, string somedata)
{
    Assert.NotEmpty(service.GetViolations(somedata));
}
```

This gives an error saying that it cannot find anything to inject for the parameter somedata. Removing the InlineDataAttribute will make the injection work. I really like the InlineData feature of xUnit so how do I get it to work with LightInject?

Comment: Try to remove double `InjectData` attribute and keep only `InlineData("data")`.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed by the LightInject author. Now it's possible to do this.